# Subject and email heading not showing in woocommerce email template

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Developing a site in wordpress and I'm using WooCommerce.
When an order is placed the siteadmin (me) and the customer are receiving an email.
The email subject field and the email header (in the message body) are properly filled in.

However when an order is complete the subject field and the email header remains empty. Of course I have filled out the settings form for this email template.

See images below.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Please advice.
[image: settings form]

[image: Empty mail subject and header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it went but suddenly, this morning it is working. As far as I know I didn't change anything. Happy it works..... thanks.